# Composition of a continuous function with functions that converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Here is problem that appeared in one of the past final exams for my introductory real analysis course, that I am having hard time to solve. It is Question 5 in 8 of the following file:

http://www.math.ubc.ca/Ugrad/pastExams/Math_321_April_2008.pdf

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a uniformly convergent sequence of
>   continuous real–valued functions defined on a metric space $M$ and let
>   $g$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}.$ Define, for each
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $h_n(x) = g(f_n(x))$.
>
> (a) Let $M = [0, 1]$. Prove that the sequence
>   $\{h_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $[0, 1]$.
>
> (b) Let $M = \mathbb{R}$. Either prove that the sequence
>   $\{h_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ or
>   provide a counterexample.

I **have** proved part (a). I am having trouble with part (b). It seems to me that part (b) has a counterexample. This is because, the key point in part (a) is that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ (because $[0,1]$ is compact), but in part (b) compactness is removed. So my guess is that counter-example will involve something like $g(x)=x^2$ (which is an example of continuous function which is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$). Is this guess correct? What would be an example of uniformly convergent sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions in this case?

I would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: I know that the question is old, but I would like to point out to anyone reading this that the OP may have committed a mistake by saying that point (a) can be proved by saying that $g$ be uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. In fact it might happen that the range of $f_n$ is even disjoint with respect to $[0,1]$ for some $n$!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Put $f_n=x-\frac 1n$ for each $n$.

Comment: Thanks! I have written my solution below based on this hint :)

Answer (score 5):

Using Alex Ravsky's hint, one such counterexample for part (b) is $f_n(x)=x-\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n$, and $g(x)=x^2$. Here is my full solution:

First of all, $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=x$, since $$\sup_{x\in R} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{1}{n}\to 0 \ \ \ \ \ \textrm{as } n\to\infty$$

We claim that the sequence of functions defined by $h_n(x)=g(f_n(x))=(x-\frac{1}{n})^2$ converges pointwise, but not uniformly to $h(x)=x^2$. Indeed, for given $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can choose $N$ so large that 
$$\frac{|2x|}{N}+\frac{1}{N^2}<\epsilon$$
Then for any $n\ge N$, we get
$$ |h_n(x)-h(x)|=\left|x^2-\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2} - x^2\right|\le \frac{|2x|}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\le\frac{|2x|}{N}+\frac{1}{N^2}<\epsilon$$
which proves pointwise convergence. The convergence is not uniform because
$$|h_n(n)-h(n)|=\left|\left(n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2-n^2\right|=2-\frac{1}{n^2}\ge 1$$
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular,
$$\sup_{x\in R} |h_n(x)-h(x)|\not\to 0\ \ \ \ \ \textrm{as } n\to\infty$$

Comment: This solution is an exact realization of my idea, so it seems to be OK and I vote up it. :-)  It seems that it the future you will write very detailed mathematical articles. :-)

Comment: @AlexRavsky Haha thanks! Hopefully one day :)