# Uniformly continuous function on uniformly convergent sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let {$f_{n} , n\in \mathbb{N}$} be a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous real–valued functions defined on a metric space $M$ and let $g$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Define, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $h_{n}(x)=g(f_{n}(x))$.
We know if $M= \mathbb{R}$ then the sequence {$h_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}$} may not be uniformly convergent. A very nice example is given here: [Composition of a continuous function with functions that converge uniformly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366116/composition-of-a-continuous-function-with-functions-that-converge-uniformly)
Now if instead, $h$ is a bounded uniformly continuous function, can we say that {$h_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}$} is uniformly convergent? 
Also, if I relax the condition on {$f_{n}, n\in \mathbb{N}$} and make it right continuous instead of continuous then will the answer remain same?

Comment: If $g$ is uniformly continuous and $f_n \to f$ uniformly then $h_n$ converges uniformly. No continuity assumptions on $f_n$'s are required. If $g$ is just bounded and continuous then $h_n$ need not converge uniformly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much. Can you give me a reference? I have to cite a reference for my work. I have searched for it but not able to find a reference.

Comment: This result follows immediately from definition of uniform continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined as follows: $g(n)=g(n+\frac 2 n)=0$, $g(n+\frac 1 n)=1$ and $g$ has a straightline graph on the intervals $(n,n+\frac 1 n)$ as well as $(n+\frac 1 n,n+\frac 2 n)$ for $n=3,4,\cdots$ and $0$ everywhere else. Then $g$ is a bounded continuous function. Let $f_n(x)=x+\frac 1 n$. Then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$ to $f(x)=x$ but $h_n$ doesn't converge uniformly: $\sup_x \{|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))| \geq |g(f_n(n))-g(f(n))|=1$ for all $n$. [My comment above has more information about the question].